# QEMU virtio/virtconsole devices explained

Tags: qemu, kvm

Let's take this example (I spent several hours to make it work):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 ... \
-kernel $HOME/devel/vmlinuz-5.11.0-22-generic            \
-drive ...                                               \
-append 'earlyprintk=hvc0 console=hvc0 root=/dev/sda rw' \ (0)
-device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0              \ (1)
-chardev stdio,id=charconsole0                           \ (2)
-device virtconsole,chardev=charconsole0,id=console0       (3)
```

What do those options do?
My understanding is that

- (2) tells qemu to create host end-point of tty/console and "binds" it to qemu's stdio.
- (3) tells qemu what devices should be exposed to the guest, and also specifies that `charconsole0` should be used as the other end, which is effectively qemu's stdio.

  - **But what is `virtconsole`**?
  - **What is the difference between `virtconsole` and `virtserialport` or `virtio-serial-pci`?**
- **What does (1) do? Where does its name: `virtio-serial-pci` come from?**
- **How do I know that `virtconsole` device in the guest will be identified with the name `hvc0` (so that I could specify it in (0))?**

Answer (score 1):

virtconsole is really just a specialised virtio-serial link. Each -device specifies a new device so in your example you have two virtio-serial devices. The virtio-serial-pci device behaves exactly like virtio-serial except it is on the PCI bus rather than the MMIO bus.